# Web browser does not hide root slash in URL between host & path

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, nginx, url, rewrite

Thanks in advance for any help provided.

---

**Update:** Tanks to [Gerard H. Pille](https://superuser.com/users/138214/gerard-h-pille), [Adrien](https://superuser.com/users/619188/adrien) replies and some logs investigations I've come to transforming question a bit.
Now I firmly realize that final slash in `http://example.com/` is not a simple trailing slash in path, but a hard documented part of URL between *port* and *path*:
`scheme:[//[user[:password]@]host[:port]][/path][?query][#fragment]`
<sup>(greatly ashamed for not knowing that)</sup>
But still, **why** doesn't my browser hide that slash in its conventional behavior? Could it be because of http: instead of https:?<sub>(very wild guess)</sub>

---

nginx/1.6.2
Apache/2.4.10
Debian 8.10

I'm using Nginx as a reverse proxy for Apache (N is processing non-php & statics, A is for php, obviously).

Somehow I can't make Nginx make a rewrite to follow common recommendation for removing trailing slash to make `http://example.net/` look like `http://example.net`

Now my nginx virtual host config file looks like this:

```
server {
    listen   80;

    root /var/www/example.net/;
    index index.html index.htm;

    server_name example.net;

    #Can't make this work as intended
    rewrite ^http://(example.net)/$ http://$1 permanent;
    #Also tried
    #rewrite ^http://(.*)/$ http://$1 permanent;
    #And
    #rewrite ^/(example.net)/$ /$1 permanent;

    location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;

     }

     location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }
}
```

**@GerardH.Pille**,
well, yes, you were right: if I regexp rewrite like `^(.*)/$ $1;`, it actually matches "/", but error Zero Length occurs... (which is unsurprising)...

```
2018/01/17 20:42:39 [notice] 1309#0: *5 "^(.*)/$" matches "/", client: 10.0.2.2, server: example.net, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "example.net"
2018/01/17 20:42:39 [notice] 1309#0: *5 rewritten data: "", args: "", client: 10.0.2.2, server: example.net, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "example.net"
2018/01/17 20:42:39 [error] 1309#0: *5 the rewritten URI has a zero length, client: 10.0.2.2, server: example.net, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "example.net"
```

But still, HOW this root slash becomes hidden at any normal site?

Comment: Where did you find that recommendation?  If I ask my browser to visit "www.duckduckgo.com", I get a redirect with header `Location 
https://duckduckgo.com/`.  This is not a trailing slash, but the start of the path, always '/'.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#Syntax   PS. but my browser hides that slash.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Yep, I know that is't start of the path :) and an identifier of a directory (not a file).

And for root it SHOULD be trailing slash, if I'm not mistaken, but unsure :)

If I've got it right from googling, such rewrites mostly do just cosmetics changes with URI in adress bar. So no redirect should occur...

In my case, if I go `example.net`, my browser doesn't hide that last slash in this particular case :(

Comment: Drop that rule, Denis, you've probably got better things to do?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille, absolutely :) But this difference is sites behavior annoys quite much... And I'd like to learn why this happens :)

Comment: set `rewrite_log on;` and `error_log xxxxx notice;`,  reload your configuration and verify if the rewrite matches your request.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille, thanks for advice, situation has become a bit clearer. Updated the Question.

Answer (score 0):

basically the browser showing a URL without the trailing slash is cosmetic only.  When it makes the request, it still asks for

GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: wherever.

etc.  in this case / is the path.  You can't have an empty path.  The root path is /.

Comment: sorry the site stripped the new line between GET / HTTP/1.1. and the Host header.  Can't edit it either... sigh.

Comment: A double space at the end of a line will put the next line down onto it's own line.

Comment: @Adrien, thanks for your reply, it is really so. I've transformed my question due to new info.